# jquery e.preventDefault(); not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have some code that when fired is working, yet the e.preventDefault(); is not firing.

originally it was inside of a for each loop which when clicked completed the task 9x (depending on the amount of loops) but the e.preventDefault(); was working fine.

ANY help appreciated (relatively new to JavaScript):

```
<script Content-Type: 'application/javascript'>

        $('.cartAdd').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).html('Adding Item To Cart')
        element = $(this)
        ajaxUrl = element.attr('href');
        $.get(ajaxUrl + '&c=?', function(response) {
        element.html('Item Added Successfully!');
        element.css('background','#1150f1');
        //$('#checkoutbtn').animate({backgroundColor: '#1150f1'}, 200)
        setTimeout(function() {
        element.html('Add To Cart');
        element.css('background','green');
                                }, 5000);
                        }).error(function(error) {
                            element.html('Error adding to cart')
                            element.css('background','red');                       
                            setTimeout(function() {
                            element.html('Add To Cart');
                            element.css('background','none');
                            }, 5000);
                        })
                    });
```

Comment: Please specify the problem and what is your need

Comment: What do you expect `e.preventDefault()` do?

Comment: "not working as expected" is not really a problem description, is it mate? please write what exactly you want to happen, and what happens instead. also, please do the following meanwhile: 1) check developer console and let us know if any errors pop up, 2) move the `e.preventDefault();` to the bottom of the click handler and see if it helps

Comment: The problem is if i place the code inside the loop - the code is running as a loop ie quantity is added 9 x

Comment: if i add the code separately (as above) the e.preventDefault(); doesnt work at all

Comment: developer console doesn't show anything as whats suppose to happen happens anyway.

e.preventDefault(); at the bottom has the same problem

Comment: Again, **what happens** that you want to prevent with preventDefault?

Comment: the code runs the link is clicked, the item is added to the cart but then the browser is re-directed

Comment: is the `.cartAdd` class set to the `<a>` element or to anything inside/outside of it ?

Comment: could you please create a fiddle/codepen/jsbin where we can see the issue ?

Comment: Yes .cartAdd is being looped above to multiple items

$('#searchResults').append("<tr class=\"table-result\"><td class=\"name\">" + items[i].name + "</td><td class=\"sku\">" + items[i].sku + "</td><td class=\"price\">" + accounting.formatMoney((items[i].price*1.2), "£ ", 2) + "</td><td class=\"quantity\"><input type='text' value='1' /></td><td class=\"cart\"><a class='cartAdd' href='http://www.thehogfathermotorcycles.com/store/checkout/cart/add?product=" + items[i].entity_id + "&qty=1'>Add To Cart</a></td>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the html **Dynamically**,you need to use a `delegate()` or `on()`.

**Reason:**
   At the time of page load these html elements are not there in the page, so jquery does not know such an element exsist in the page.Therefore Jquery provides `on()` and `delegate()`,which will act as a delegate for the dynamically added html elements.

You should use

```
$('body').on('click','.cartAdd',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

or you could use a delegate

```
 $('body').delegate('.cartAdd','click',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Hope this helps,
thank you

Comment: That made a header error appear because i was calling it twice, once i removed the duplicate header the delegate code above worked!

thanks SarathSprakash